# Pattern or solution for using classes with different interface the same way

Tags: php, design-patterns, interfaces, patterns-and-practices, architectural-patterns

What I would like to achieve is to use classes (now two, later more) with different interface the same way, so I would like avoid using decisions based on the interface on upper levels for instance, I don't want to see things like this:

```
if ($class instanceof 'ThisInterface') {
    $thisInterfaceImplementation->doStuff();
}
```

Instead, I would like to call the method like $class->doStuff() and put the decisions into a wrapper like class. I would like to avoid empty methods also.

I'm thinking about to use Wrapper or Adapter (and maybe Observer), but I'm curious, maybe there is a better way to do this.

To be more clear here is a small explanation what I try to solve.
We are building an application that has to communicate with printing houses. This means we have to add an additional page(s) to the print sheets (or not, or maybe different way), maybe we have to rename the pdf files on ftp this or that way, or not at all.

We have a couple decisions to made based on the printers (on our interfaces), but at different steps or processes, therefore I think Strategy pattern wouldn't be a good fit (and I would have to create empty methods or use those ifs)

The Observer pattern seems to solve all my "problems", but it might be an overkill in this case. With this, I could simply dispatch events at the points I have to make a decision and only the observers subscribed to this event would do the necessary things. No empty methods, not much problem with different interfaces. On the other hand, we would dispatch every event only one place in the code, so this seems to be a "miss usage" of this pattern.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you building the API to the printers? Can you make those APIs conform to an interface you designed.

Comment: Sadly, no I can't change anything regarding what and how the printers do expect from us. We have specifications how we should deal with the different printers. We need different ones, because one can print black&white stuff cheaper and the other one is better with coloured printing.

Comment: Then I'd go with wrappers which will all conform to whatever interface you need. This seems the simplest approach given what you've got there.

Comment: I think I agree with Pinetree on this.  Wrapper seems to be the simplest approach while ensuring that you can do everything you require.  Use a Factory pattern if you wind up having to use a lot of different Wrapper classes for your interfaces.

Comment: I agree, too. "Wrapper pattern" has exactly the purpose to make an incompatible interface compatible - so why do you hesitate?

Comment: [Bridge](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBridge.aspx) pattern.  But be careful that you extract commonality from each different low level interface into the higher level interfaces.  Otherwise you are going to be repeating the same code for each implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andyz. For me, the Bridge pattern seems to be using implementors with common interface. In my case, the implementors don't have fully compatible interfaces. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think a simple Template demands tight adherence to a common interface. But Bridge, as it sounds, is much richer.   My thought is, if it lets you **vary the interface independently of the abtraction** it should help to express your design.

Comment: It seems to me the Bridge lets you build up 'levels of compatibility' so that  **implementation interface** ( exactly what you is supported ) can continue to evolve, but the common link , the abstraction, the concept of **printing as a whole** can remain stable, until you decide to alter it, to take advantage of specific new points in the interface.

Comment: Be advised, these patterns tend to meld together.  ( http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge ) "Adapter [**wrapper**] makes things work after they’re designed; Bridge makes them work before they are.
Bridge is designed up-front to let the abstraction and the implementation vary independently. Adapter is retrofitted to make unrelated classes work together."